# How can I use pictures that are in a separate folder with Python 3.4?

Tags: python, directory

I have a program that has a lot of stuff in it. (Photos, text files and other things). I would like to be able to organize all those files by putting the files in a separate folder. I don't know how to do this. So my question is, how can I move the files but have Python still be able to find them. I have not been able to find other answers relating to this. Thanks. If you need to view some of the code, here it is:

If I want to open my text files, I use this.

```
text_file = open("takingInventory.txt", "r")
takingInventoryInfo = text_file.read()
text_file.close()
```

When I want to open a picture, I use this.

```
image = Image.open("pgraniteRecipe.png")
```

Comment: Would you mind sharing some code of what you are doing?

Comment: @ITellMyselfSecrets I currently have no code for finding other directories, but I will share the code for what I am doing now.

Comment: Are you trying to move the files from within the python program? Or move it outside and access from inside the program? Either way  the os module is what you need here. It gives you all the tools necessary to work with directory structure from within your python script.

Comment: If you are writing a python package, you could place the images into a folder within the package, and then use the following code as your "root" directory. `os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)), "pictures")` This will locate the directory automatically to you, and will get you to the `pictures` folder in the base folder of a script that ran that code.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question right. I think the [`os`](https://docs.python.org/3.1/library/os.html) module can do what you need. Just declare the path of the new folder you just created then join the path of the folder with the name of the file.

```
import os
new_folder = "Path/to/new/folder"
text_file = open(os.path.join(new_folder,"takingInventory.txt"), "r")
takingInventoryInfo = text_file.read()
text_file.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

All you need is to supply the full path to the file:

```
with  open("full/path/to/takingInventory.txt") as  text_file:
        ....
```

If you are [creating a python application for distribution](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-package-and-distribute-python-applications) you can [create a package](http://www.pythoncentral.io/how-to-create-a-python-package/) structure that enables python to find any file relative to the folders in your package but if a user moves or renames a file or folder then you are in trouble. Python has no way of knowing if a user has moved  or renamed any files.

You can use a try/except to open the files and do whatever is needed in the case where the file is not available anymore:

```
try:
    f = open("missing.file")         
except IOError as e:
    print(e.errno)
    # do whatever is relevant to warn the user here
```

There are specific error codes for different IOErrors, you can be more specific as to what action you take based on the [errno](https://docs.python.org/2/library/errno.html) returned:

```
import errno

print(errno.errorcode)
{1: 'EPERM', 2: 'ENOENT', 3: 'ESRCH', 4: 'EINTR', 5: 'EIO', 6: 'ENXIO', 7: 'E2BIG', 8: 'ENOEXEC', 9: 'EBADF', 10: 'ECHILD', 11: 'EAGAIN', 12: 'ENOMEM', 13: 'EACCES', 14: 'EFAULT', 15: 'ENOTBLK', 16: 'EBUSY', 17: 'EEXIST', 18: 'EXDEV', 19: 'ENODEV', 20: 'ENOTDIR', 21: 'EISDIR', 22: 'EINVAL', 23: 'ENFILE', 24: 'EMFILE', 25: 'ENOTTY', 26: 'ETXTBSY', 27: 'EFBIG', 28: 'ENOSPC', 29: 'ESPIPE', 30: 'EROFS', 31: 'EMLINK', 32: 'EPIPE', 33: 'EDOM', 34: 'ERANGE', 35: 'EDEADLOCK', 36: 'ENAMETOOLONG', 37: 'ENOLCK', 38: 'ENOSYS', 39: 'ENOTEMPTY', 40: 'ELOOP', 42: 'ENOMSG', 43: 'EIDRM', 44: 'ECHRNG', 45: 'EL2NSYNC', 46: 'EL3HLT', 47: 'EL3RST', 48: 'ELNRNG', 49: 'EUNATCH', 50: 'ENOCSI', 51: 'EL2HLT', 52: 'EBADE', 53: 'EBADR', 54: 'EXFULL', 55: 'ENOANO', 56: 'EBADRQC', 57: 'EBADSLT', 59: 'EBFONT', 60: 'ENOSTR', 61: 'ENODATA', 62: 'ETIME', 63: 'ENOSR', 64: 'ENONET', 65: 'ENOPKG', 66: 'EREMOTE', 67: 'ENOLINK', 68: 'EADV', 69: 'ESRMNT', 70: 'ECOMM', 71: 'EPROTO', 72: 'EMULTIHOP', 73: 'EDOTDOT', 74: 'EBADMSG', 75: 'EOVERFLOW', 76: 'ENOTUNIQ', 77: 'EBADFD', 78: 'EREMCHG', 79: 'ELIBACC', 80: 'ELIBBAD', 81: 'ELIBSCN', 82: 'ELIBMAX', 83: 'ELIBEXEC', 84: 'EILSEQ', 85: 'ERESTART', 86: 'ESTRPIPE', 87: 'EUSERS', 88: 'ENOTSOCK', 89: 'EDESTADDRREQ', 90: 'EMSGSIZE', 91: 'EPROTOTYPE', 92: 'ENOPROTOOPT', 93: 'EPROTONOSUPPORT', 94: 'ESOCKTNOSUPPORT', 95: 'ENOTSUP', 96: 'EPFNOSUPPORT', 97: 'EAFNOSUPPORT', 98: 'EADDRINUSE', 99: 'EADDRNOTAVAIL', 100: 'ENETDOWN', 101: 'ENETUNREACH', 102: 'ENETRESET', 103: 'ECONNABORTED', 104: 'ECONNRESET', 105: 'ENOBUFS', 106: 'EISCONN', 107: 'ENOTCONN', 108: 'ESHUTDOWN', 109: 'ETOOMANYREFS', 110: 'ETIMEDOUT', 111: 'ECONNREFUSED', 112: 'EHOSTDOWN', 113: 'EHOSTUNREACH', 114: 'EALREADY', 115: 'EINPROGRESS', 116: 'ESTALE', 117: 'EUCLEAN', 118: 'ENOTNAM', 119: 'ENAVAIL', 120: 'EISNAM', 121: 'EREMOTEIO', 122: 'EDQUOT', 123: 'ENOMEDIUM', 124: 'EMEDIUMTYPE', 125: 'ECANCELED', 126: 'ENOKEY', 127: 'EKEYEXPIRED', 128: 'EKEYREVOKED', 129: 'EKEYREJECTED', 130: 'EOWNERDEAD', 131: 'ENOTRECOVERABLE', 132: 'ERFKILL'}
```

Bottom line is even after creating a good package structure there is no magic way to know if a user deletes, moves, renames etc.. any of your package files.

Comment: Okay, I'll try this. Also, the program may not always be in the same directory. The files may be moved around based on how the user installs the program. How can I make it find the text and picture files no matter where it is installed at?

Comment: are you making a package to be distributed?

Comment: Yes, I am making it available for users to download and run.

Comment: Ok then I would recommend something like Pyinstaller. https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/wiki. But If a user moves folders or renames etc.. there is no way for python to automatically know.

Comment: Okay, so would there be a way that I make the program detect if the files are not available. So I can make a popup that states that the program needs to be reinstalled.

Comment: @AustinHargis, Yes , a simple try/except and the appropriate action when the exception happens will work

Answer (score 0):

If you are writing a python package to be distributed, and have a file structure like so:

```
base/
    __init__.py
    apples.py
    bananas.py
    cherries.py
    main.py
    pictures/
        # a whole bunch of pictures
```

in your `__init__.py` file, you can have a variable listed called `base_directory`, like so:

```
base_dir = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
```

When run, `base_dir` will be the entire path structure that `__init__.py` is in. For example, on my computer, if the init file were located on some random folder on my desktop, I can import base_dir into my other scripts and it would read:

```
>>> base_dir
'/users/zinedine/desktop/python/base'
```

I can then use `os.path.join` as needed like this (if going to the pictures folder):

```
pictures_dir = os.path.join(base_dir, "pictures")
>>> pictures_dir
'/users/zinedine/desktop/python/base/pictures'
```

If you know the folder of where it is in, and you are concerned about whether some files are missing, you can use the [`glob`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/glob.html) module.

Comment: If a user deletes or moves a file then it is all the same whatever structure you have

Comment: If you know the folder of where it is in, and you are concerned about whether some files are missing, you can use the `glob` module.

Comment: what is it has been deleted, renamed on a separate partition?